# 10,000+ keyword string matching in large text files with parallelization. Python, GPU

Tags: python, parallel-processing, string-matching, numba

I want to find and extract lines, that contains  one of 10,000+ keywords from huge text files.

Wingrep is a good tool, but its keyword length is limited and it is single core. So far I did a simple python script that goes through each line and each keyword string with the `in` operator. This works well, but is incredibly slow because the huge keywords number. The code looks so far like this:

```
data_list = [# data here]            # extracted from TXT file \n character removed
keyword_list = [#keywords here]      # extracted from TXT file \n character removed
result_list = []                     # empty array for the results

for line in data_list:
    for keyword in keyword_list:
        if keyword in line:
            result_list.append(line)

#save result_list to txt file
```

Multiple CPU core version is still too slow(6x faster for 5 more core).
I have a GTX 1070 and Cuda cores could be perfect for parallelization of this. Maybe Numba could do this, but it is out of my knowledge level.

Question: Anyone can recommend a method or a code that could use the parallel power of a GPU for string matching like this?

Edit: Examples for data and keywords:

```
data_list = ("usa.newyork.greenstreet.12", "france.paris.blueroad.8", "italy.rome.pinksquare.2","greenland.narsaq.whiteroad.15")
keywordlist = ("green", "black", "blue")
```

I need both results from Country and road place.